# how to run installed python module

Tags: python, python-module

First, I installed [pygeobuf](https://github.com/mapbox/pygeobuf).

After it was installed, I didn't know how to use it. The doc said it doesn't work for windows.

In windows, I had tried all kinds of ways, but still failed.

In windows command line,

```
python (get into interpreter)

import geobuf
geobuf.encode("city_streets.geojson", "c.pbf")

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\geobuf-1.1.0-py2.7.egg\geobuf_init_.py"
, line 8, in encode
return Encoder().encode(*args)
File "C:\PYTHON27\lib\site-packages\geobuf-1.1.0-py2.7.egg\geobuf\encode.py",
line 30, in encode
self.e = pow(10, precision) # multiplier for converting coordinates into int
egers
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'str'
```

Can you show me where I am wrong?

Comment: So, the documentation says it doesn't work on windows, and you tried it and it doesn't work on windows...? What makes you think it should work?

Comment: How did you install `pygeobuf`? `!pip install pygeobuf` doesn't work.

Comment: Ended up being `!pip install geobuf`

Answer (score 0):

`encode()` takes 2 parameters, one is a loaded `json` file and the second is an optional precision value.

The correct usage is as follows:

```
import json
import geobuf


# replace with path to city_streets file
with open("city_streets.geojson") as file:
    loadedJson = json.load(file)

encoded = geobuf.encode(loadedJson)

print(encoded)
```